# Macintosh HD not showing up on disc utility

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, install

I am trying to do a clean install on my Macbook Pro 13" from 2011.
Here is what I did so far:

1) Booted up on my USB Stick with Mountain Lion Installer mounted on it

2) Opened up Disc Utility and formatted the Hard Drive. On this step I selected that I wanted to encrypt it as I always did and put my usual password in it

3) Exited Disc Utility and started the Installation process

Problem: It froze on 18min left and I waited for about an hour. Following a post on the apple forums, I simply reseted it waiting for it to resume. However it did not come up.

When I enter Recovery Mode, the Hard Drive is not there anymore. And I think because of that I get a error message when trying to execute the installation again, telling me to try again because it failed (doesn't even start).

I am hopeless now. Tried opening the terminal and listing the volumes available by

```
diskutil coreStorage list
```

But it says there is no volumes to show. Already tried reseting the NVRAM as well.

Is there a way to restore the hard drive and restart the installation?

Comment: `diskutil coreStorage list` won't return anything if you don't use a Fusion Drive. `diskutil list` will.

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up. I used coreStorage because that is what I have used before and worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it some time and tried reseting the NVRAM again (cmd+P+R on start-up).

This time it did work, or I did something wrong on the first time, I guess. The Recovery Mode opened up and there it was the "Macintosh HD" listed again.